# Gradle and Maven with 3d party jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, gradle

i need some help for a (i thought) simple use case with gradle and maven.

I have project A, that uses as compile dependency a "jar" file in a lib folder.
I have a project B that has a compile dependency on A

I want to deploy A and B into my local maven repository separately.

Right now, when i gradle install A i don't have any jar deployed to the maven repository, so that when i run B i get a NoClassDefFound on one of the classes in the jar.

### How to deploy jar into maven using gradle so that B can use A without problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your Gradle build additionally publish your jar dependency but that wouldn't fix your problem. You would then have to update your dependency to be an external module dependency, rather than a file dependency, so that the resultant POM would include this dependency. I'd suggest one of the following options.

1. Upload the jar dependency to your Maven repository and change project A's dependency to an external module dependency.
2. If that is not possible because the jar is non-static, then you could use something like the [Gradle shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to bundle the dependency in project A's jar.